# How get row by index $sheet->getRowIterator()?

Tags: php, phpoffice

For example I need get only second row in current sheet without foreach.

`foreach ( $sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) { ... }`. How access to $sheet->getRowIterator() by index without foreach, or how start foreach from another position, not from beginning.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a [on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Using `$sheet->getRowIterator()[1]` ?